# My laptop lenovo b460e has a wireless connectivity issue

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, lenovo-laptop

I checked the bios says wireless is enabled. The wifi switch is also on. But, the system is not able to search for or locate Wifi router. When I troubleshoot or try to set up a new connection, the only responses i get are for ethernet connection not wireless. BTW, My system is 32 bit.

The WLAN Autoconfig was initially not started, i started it and made it automatic and tried restarting. The is the only device that has an error in device manager is ACPI\VPC2004 *VPC2004. But since these are power management tools, i dont think they would play a role: and under my network adapter it only says "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller"...

Could this be a driver issue or a hardware issue? In either case what is to be done.
Is there some patch that would automatically install the required drivers from lenovo site?
please help

I am using windows 7 premium. I'm not sure which is the wireless card i have. so not sure which driver to install if at all necessary...

Comment: Are we to assume that you are on Windows, given the `ACPI\VPC2004...`.  If so, Windows 7, 8...?  Did you go to the Lenovo site and install their drivers for your laptop?

Comment: Go to `System settings` => `Device Manager` => `Network Adapters`. What does it show? Is there a device marked with yellow exclamation mark? You could also check Lenovo's website for a newer wifi driver.

Comment: @ott , there is no yellow flag, butin the network adapter, it only says "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller"

Comment: The Realtek is the LAN adapter. Go to http://support.lenovo.com/de_DE/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?DocID=HT072902 and download the wifi driver.

Comment: tried installing drivers using the link @ott provided. But error message popped up saying "No matching wireless"

Comment: Have you tried the link on that page `can't figure out what my wlan adapter is`?